# I accidentally paused the Linux display process

Tags: process

After installing Linux Mint 19 I wanted to check how vsinc affects fps in Linux, so I typed this command: `CLUTTER_SHOW_FPS=1 cinnamon --replace`

After some time I accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and paused that process. Immediately my Bash shell and everything except the mouse cursor froze, so I can't type the `fg` command.

Is there a way to unpause that process without rebooting and should I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> next time to properly exit that process?

Comment: Next time, run it with `CLUTTER_SHOW_FPS=1 cinnamon --replace &` to start it in the background.  Replacing it *again* with a process with a process started without `CLUTTER_SHOW_FPS` should do what you want.  Or yeah you can control-C it; X11 works with no window manager; your terminal emulator should still be visible for you to start another window manager.

Comment: i suggest always having SSH access to a machine you don't want to hard reset, but this should not be your primary fix for this issue

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Switch to a new TTY. See [How to switch between tty and xorg session?](/q/167386) for tips on how to switch TTYs.
2. Determine the PID of the cinnamon process: `ps -e | grep cinnamon`
3. Send this process the SIGCONT signal with `kill -SIGCONT [pid]`

Comment: +1. Clarification on the statement "kill [...] process with the signal" would be good. The naming of the kill utility is unfortunate, given that most of the signals one can send are not used to 'kill' a process in the sense of mortality. `kill -SIGCONT 9999` will send the continue signal to the pid 9999.

Comment: `pgrep` is useful for finding processes

Comment: Why does my desktop on tty7 gets distorted - all black and without linux start menu? Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: @Tomislav can you clarify what you mean by distorted? It sounds a bit like your tty7 just has a regular (GUI-less) shell rendering.

Comment: It looks like normal desktop after booting but without start menu panel (icons on desktop are also visible).

Comment: Perhaps some configuration got corrupted?

Answer (score 10):

Short, concrete version of [CameronNemo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462419/54602):

> <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> <sup><sub># Switch to TTY1</sub></sup>
> user name<kbd>↲</kbd> <sub><sub># Log in on this terminal</sub></sub>
> password<kbd>↲</kbd>
> `killall -SIGCONT cinnamon`<kbd>↲</kbd> <sup><sub># Send the continue signal to the process</sub></sup>
> <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> <sup><sub># Log out on TTY1</sub></sup>
> <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> <sup><sub># Switch back to the graphical environment</sub></sup>

<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd> here assume that you have X running on TTY7, as is standard on Ubuntu and, I assume, also on Mint.